# How to select from dataframe when column is optional

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark (scala) dataframe where a few of the dataframe columns are optional, that is, sometimes they don't exist. Is there a very simple way to modify my `df.select` statement so that spark doesn't care that the column might not exist?

For example, right now I have: `df.select(Seq(col("col1"), col("optionalCol"), col("col2")))`.

I was hoping there would be some kind of "optional" designation.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Spark 1.6.x? In spark 2.0 and higher, a Dataframe is just a Dataset[Row], so answers will look different.

Answer (score 5):

You can get take the columns you might care about, and then filter out the ones that don't exist in the dataframe.

```
val dfColumns = df.columns.toSet
val columns: Seq[String] = Seq("col1","optionalcol","col2").filter(dfColumns)
df.select(columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

You can use the following to check if the column exists or not

```
// returns true if the column exists else returns false
if(df.columns.contains("optional_col")) {
         df.select(Seq(col("col1"), col("optionalCol"), col("col2")))
}    
else {
        df.select(Seq(col("col1"),  col("col2")))
}
```

Comment: Handy, but as we are using structure for DFs, it does not seem a wise approach to me. It sort of goes against the notion of this